# Beautiful Soup find elements having hidden style

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My simple need.
How do I find elements that are not visible on the webpage currently? I am guessing `style="visibility:hidden"` or `style="display:none"` are simple ways to hide an element, but BeautifulSoup doesn't know if its hidden or not.

For example, HTML is:

```
Textbox_Invisible1: <input id="tbi1" type="text" style="visibility:hidden">
Textbox_Invisible2: <input id="tbi2" type="text" class="hidden_elements">
Textbox1: <input id="tb1" type="text">
```

So my first concern is that BeautifulSoup cannot find out if any of the above textboxes are hidden:

```
# Python 2.7
# Import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = """Textbox_Invisible1: <input id="tbi1" type="text" style="visibility:hidden">
...  Textbox_Invisible2: <input id="tbi2" type="text" class="hidden_elements">
...  Textbox1: <input id="tb1" type="text">"""
>>> soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source)
>>> soup1.find(id='tb1').hidden
False
>>> soup1.find(id='tbi1').hidden
False
>>> soup1.find(id='tbi2').hidden
False
>>>
```

My only question is, is there a way to find out which elements are hidden?
(We have to consider the complex HTML also where the  having elements might be hidden)

Comment: Why do you need to know which elements are hidden? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to find all the HTML elements that are ONLY visible to the user

Comment: Sure - but what is the purpose of doing that? Maybe there is another (more realistic) way of achieving your actual goal. Trying to use an html parser to interpret css style rules is obviously never going to work (unless the html is very, very simple).

Comment: So, the goal is to find visible web elements based on text seen on webpage. I have decided to use selenium visible method

Comment: any chance you could accept my answer then? It suggests the exact sort of thing you've decided to do :) it's http://stackoverflow.com/a/8766424/1129851

Answer (score 4):

BeautifulSoup is an *html parser*, not a browser. It doesn't know anything about how the page is supposed to be rendered, calculated DOM attributes etc, it's checking where the angle brackets begin and end.

If you need to work with the DOM at runtime, you'd be better off with a browser automation package, i.e. something that will start the browser, let the browser consume the page, and then expose browser controls and the calculated DOM. Depending on the platform, you have different options. Have a look at [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming) on the Python WIki for ideas, check the section *Python Wrappers around Web "Libraries" and Browser Technology*.

Comment: Hi Giacomo,
Thanks for the reply!! Yes, I clearly got your point. I am actually using Selenium already for that. 

So, let me explain you 1st in detail what I am trying to achieve so that you can suggest me a better way.
There is a webpage which has all the HTML elements like:
http://www.mayukhbose.com/elements.html

Cont... in next comment

Comment: Continued here...

What I wish to do is, from Python make simple methods/functions that can automate interactions with the HTML elements. For e.g: click_button(button_name='Send Data'). I can easily write these methods using Selenium's Python Client. However, the Selenium's Python Client only takes element locators as parameters. Now, I need to somehow create these locators based on the text found on the webpage. This can be done by parsing the webpage (where BeautifulSoup is really useful). I hope you get my idea. thanks, Amit

Comment: From a cursory look at the Selenium documentation, it seems like you can locate elements by DOM; if that's true, you should be able to get the node members related to style, or in the worst case the "style" attribute *should* contain the full css declaration specific to that node. But I'm not an expert in Selenium, so I wouldn't know; I've done this sort of stuff in the past with the win32 bindings on IE only.

Answer (score 2):

With BeautifulSoup, I'm afraid you'll need to explicitly check the attributes used to make the elements hidden:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
tbi1 = soup.find(id='tbi1')
tbi2 = soup.find(id='tbi2')
print tbi1['style'] == 'visibility:hidden'
print tbi2['class'] == 'hidden_elements'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But then, it gets so complicated if the parent is hidden. Also, if elements are hidden for a class, I will need to know which classes hide element and which do not. I just want to find all the elements that are not hidden. Any solution? Thanks

Comment: If you need to know details about classes, then you'll need to parse the css also.

Answer (score 0):

try this (bs4), works for me:

```
print soup1.select( '[style~="visibility:hidden"]' )
print soup1.select( '[style~="display:none"]' )
```

.select method used CSS2 selectors:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification in the first post, I think this meets the need of only finding all elements hidden to the user at load time (not dynamic or calculated rendering but the raw source sent to the process).

If dynamically rendered, then you should be using something like Selenium to view the current state of source that is subject to change based on any number of criteria (user role, public private, something clicked or not clicked, or something that changes onload)

I'm roughing this out in my head, so please forgive, but this:

````py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = """Textbox_Invisible1: <input id="tbi1" type="text" style="visibility:hidden">
Textbox_Invisible2: <input id="tbi2" type="text" class="hidden_elements">
Textbox1: <input id="tb1" type="text">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

# returns a list of 'bs4.element.Tag' objects where style=visibility:hidden
# for class change {"style":"visibility:hidden"} to {"class":"hidden_elements"}
all_my_visible_elements = soup.find_all(True, {"style":"visibility:hidden"})```
````

Answer (score -1):

Hey maybe someone still needs this
some a tip i'm using is top replace the `<!-- with blank`
like this
`soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text.replace('<!--','') ,'html.parser')`
it works fine to me depends on the html source maybe you need to make some changes