# check if a css class position is fixed using python

Tags: python, css

I've write a simple web parser to parse a website using beautiful soap. But i want to know wether a class css attribute "postion" is fiexd or absolute.

All the css attribute are css links defined in html header, with class attribute in the css file like this

```
.slideABox , .slideBBox{
    max-width:320px; position:relative; margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So how can i check the attribute of a css class in python, just like in javascript?

Comment: I don't use beautiful soup, but this might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8579571/2537637

Comment: thank you for your reference, i'am trying Selenium to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is a poor choice for what you want to accomplish, because it does not come with a rendering engine (therefore, CSS rules are not even taken in consideration when parsing the page).

Obviously you could parse the CSS rules manually using an appropriate tool (e.g. http://pythonhosted.org/tinycss/), but I won't recommend that because CSS properties can also be inherited, and you'll end up with false results, unless your HTML page is a very simple one.

Instead, I suggest to take a look to [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which is essentially a browser wrapper, and has Python bindings. Its Element object has a `value_of_css_property` method, which will probably suit your needs (see the [APIs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) here).

Comment: i need the dynamic css property of an element, and Selenium is exactly the one i am looking for. i am tring it. thank you for your advice.